# Removing a space from the start of a array to use strcmp

Tags: c

Hello I am doing a looping on my code with fgets and I want that when user introduces the word `"bye"` the program ends, so I have a do while like this:

```
char buf[1000]

do{

    fgets(buf, 1000, stdin);
    
    //More code here

while(strcmp(buf, "bye")!=0);
```

But I have a problem that it is, when user made a space or a tab or multiple spaces before write bye the strcmp doesnt recognize him as bye, so the program only exits when users only type bye without any previous `space or tab`.

I want to know how can I prevent the spaces or tabs before the by word to exits if user type for example:

```
'     bye'
```

Comment: @dratenik My bad on my program I use malloc and realloc to buf! But my problem was not that

Comment: @dratenik I know that when I put the first thing to '\0' the strlen will read the array until find a '\0' thats why doesnt work! I dont know I has posted that my stupid idea, so I dont know how to prevent the spaces or \t from user befor isertion of bye! So anything will work because the first position will be '\0', so I know that I cant do that

Comment: You probably want to use `strstr()` instead. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm

Comment: Use `strspn()` to skip bytes: `char *word; … word = buf + strspn(buf, " \t\n\r\f");` and then `strcmp(word, "bye")` in your condition.  Of course, if you need to ignore trailing white space too (and you probably do since `fgets()` keeps the newline at the end), you have more work to do — you need a function instead of just a call to `strspn()`.

Comment: Many ways. Examples:  Can use a function like `sscanf` to get the next non-whitespace word. Or trim the whitespaces before calling `strcmp`.

Comment: If one is going to use this a lot, it's worth learning `lex/re2c` to greatly simplify the code and reduce errors. Especially [re2c](https://re2c.org/) will be great for this simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` reads in a complete line, including any starting white spaces and also including the new line character at the end of the line. Even if a user does not enter preceding white spaces, the content of `buf` is likely to be `"bye\n"`, such that `buf` will hardly compare equal to `"bye"` when using `strcmp`.

I'd suggest to scan the buffer for a single word using `sscanf` and compare this word to `"bye"` then. Note that `scanf("%s"...`) skips white space characters at the beginning of a word and stops before the first white space after the word.

```
   char isStopWord[20];
   isStopWord[0] = '\0';
   sscanf(buf,"%19s",isStopWord);
}
while(strcmp(isStopWord, "bye")!=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It a very strange requirement to use `strcmp` to remove characters from the array but everything is possible :)

```
char *removeSpacesAndTabsBeginning(char *str)
{
    size_t len;
    char savedc;
    if(str && *str)
    {
        len = strlen(str);
        savedc = str[1];
        str[1] = 0;
        while(!strcmp(str, " "))
        {
            str[1] = savedc;
            memmove(str, str + 1, len);
            savedc = str[1];
            str[1] = 0;
        }
        str[1] = savedc;
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char z[] = "  \t\tHello World.";
    printf("`%s`\n", removeSpacesAndTabsBeginning(z));
}
```

If you want to know if the string contains `"bye"` use `strstr`.

```
int isBye(const char *str)
{
    return !!strstr(str, "bye");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- you should test the return value of `fgets()` to detect unexpected end of file.
- you should ignore whitespace in the comparison. You should just trim the string read by `fgets()` as the other code probably does not handle these either.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[1000];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        size_t i = 0, length = strlen(buf);
        /* trim trailing white space */
        while (length > 0 && isspace((unsigned char)buf[length - 1])) {
            buf[--length] = '\0';
        }
        /* trim leading white space */
        while (isspace((unsigned char)buf[i]) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            memmove(buf, buf + i, length - i + 1);
        }
        // check for end command
        if (!strcmp(buf, "bye"))
            break;
    
        //More code here: handle other commands
        //...
    }
    return 0;
}
```